# Zikula CMS -- Finding User Properties

Tags: twig, zikula

This question involves the Zikula CMS. Is it possible to detect if a viewer is logged in and is a member of a specific group using twig? I would like to have some control code that doesn't show ad blocks if a user is a paying subscriber (is a member of a specific group). Thanks!

Comment: its symfony based try to write {{ dump() }} to show what you get on your view

Comment: Thanks I will try that.

Comment: if you switch to `dev` mode you will get more reasonable output from `{{ dump() }}`

Answer (score 1):

For most checks like this you won't check for group memberships, but for permissions which are granted by them.
So you could for example add a condition like the following to your Twig template:

```
{% if currentUser.loggedIn and hasPermission('MyComponent::', '.*', ACCESS_READ) %}
    special block for paying members
{% else %}
    show ad
{% endif %}
```

Note that `MyComponent` can be anything, it is not limited to components used/provided by your installed extensions.

You can read more about the `currentUser` global variable [here](https://github.com/zikula/core/blob/master/src/docs/Twig/GlobalVariables.md#currentuser).